# SwingWorker issue, method doInBackground not executed?

Tags: java, swing, swingworker

Sometimes the doInBackgorund() method of my SwingWorker seems not to be executed, it goes directly to the done() method without saving or printing anything on some of my clients machines, so i suppose it's a random thing , and i can't figure out why. Here 's my code :

```
public class saveCmdWorker extends SwingWorker<Integer, Integer> {

    Order ord;

    public saveCmdWorker(Order ord) {
        this.ord = ord;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer doInBackground() {
        if(999 != ord.getCaissier().getIdCaissier())                           
            saveCmd(ord); // database queries
        else
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);

            if(ord.isIsProd() == false){
            try {
                // print via serial port
                Printer.print(ord, false, Restaurant.numCaisse); 
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                PosO2.errorLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Printing error", ex);

                }
            }
            try {

                Printer.printFacture(ord, false);

                if(btnDuplicata.getForeground() == Color.red)
                    Printer.printFacture(ord, true);


            } catch (Exception ex) {
                PosO2.errorLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Printing error", ex);
            }

        return 1;
    }

    @Override
    protected void done() {
        try {

            btnDuplicata.setForeground(Color.black);                     
            ARendre = 0.0;
            ord.clear();

            for (int j = 0; j < tab_paiement.size(); j++) {
                tab_paiement.get(j).setVisible(true);
            }

            montantRestant.setBackground(Color.red);
        } catch(Exception e) {
                PosO2.errorLogger.log(Level.SEVERE, "Refresh Error", e);
        }
    }
}
```

I execute this worker via this actionlistener :

```
ActionListener encaissListener = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                    worker = new saveCmdWorker(cmd);
                    worker.execute();

            }
        };
```

I don't have any logs available so i assume no exception is caught. I saw that a JOptionPane was fired in the doInBackground()(consider as ui modification in an other thread?) but the problem exists when the application doesn't go in the else statement. Can this be the cause of my problems? I don't have this bug on my computer, it just works fine.

Comment: Yes, opening a JOptionPane is considered as a UI modification so you should not do that in doInBackground. Also, please follow Java naming conventions: Classes start with an Upper case letter. Variables start with lower case letter. Your code is unreadable as such. Also avoid this `if(ord.isIsProd() == false)` and rather simply type `if(!ord.isIsProd())`

Comment: Ok thnks for the advices I'll correct that, but if the JOptionPane is actually not opened, it still can be the cause of the method not being executed?

Comment: Since you are violating the single-thread of Swing, the outcome can be quite unpredictable and you could end up having the JOptionPane not visible alhtough you invoked showMessageDialog. showMessageDialog is a blocking call so you could be stuck there. To be sure, use the JConsole and look at the stacktrace state of the SwingWorker threads or even better use a debugger and set a few breakpoints in your doInBackground method, this will quickly lead you to your problems.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something you're not actually invoking `SwingWorker.get()` in your `done` implementation - which means that if an exception occured within the worker (e.g. say `ord.getCaissier()` returns null) you won't see any log messages. Thus, there still may be another error hidden in there, although Guillaume Polet's answer is probably the reason here.

Answer (score 0):

As per the SwingWorker documentation (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html#execute()):

> SwingWorker is only designed to be executed once. Executing a SwingWorker more than once will not result in invoking the doInBackground method twice.

So, it looks like you need to create a new instance of your subclass each time you want to run the execute method properly.